# Viewing image in browser from database PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am trying to create a form that uploads an image to a database and displays the image on the webpage. When I upload an image, the image is added to the database, however it is not displayed on the webpage. It only displays an image icon. I am not receiving any error messages. Here is the uploadpage.php code:

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))
    echo "That is not an image.";
else
{
    $image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageSize = @getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if ($imageSize==FALSE)
        echo "That is not an image.";
    else
    {
        if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO storeImage VALUES('','$imageName','$image')"))
            echo "Problem Uploading Image";
        else
        {
            $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
            echo "Image Uploaded.<p/>Your image:<p/><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
        }       
    }
}
```

And the get.php code:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'storeImage' WHERE 'id'=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You should quote your src attribute in your img element because it contains an equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

How about you store the image in the filesystem and save the url to the image in the database instead? Because, from my POV (though I am not well versed in saving binary data to databases), whatever you're doing seems confusing to me. I would rather save the image's location after it's uploaded in the filesystem and store it into the database.

You can then pull it from the database using `<img src="<?php echo $image['image_url'];?>">`.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload your image to project folder like "Upload" and image name send to database, then you can get image name from database and you can give path to web page with image name

see https://www.formget.com/upload-images-using-php-and-jquery-via-form/

Answer (score 0):

Your database might not support images so I suggest you store the uploaded images into a folder like `/images` and name each one with an id like `176379.png` then storing its path in a database. Then when you need to display it, you can use something like something like `echo '<img src="{$image}"'>`